# Do the extension library controls work for Blackberry's?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've been using the built in Extension Library controls in Notes 9 to convert a simple Notes app to a mobile (browser based) app.  It seems to work fine on an Android and iPhone, but I can't seem to find any information on how to check if it works on a Blackberry.

If you look at the 8.5.3XL Teamroom template, you'll see a blackberry theme, but how can we check how it looks?  By default, if I open my "mobile.xsp", I'll see the Android version.  Adding "?platform=iphone" would open the iPhone styles.  How can I test this for Blackberries?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only two values that seem to seem to cause the Xpages mobile theme to be anything but android on a browser are ?platform=iphone and ?platform=blackberry. Unfortunately ?platform=blackberry seems to trigger the iOS theme being used instead of a blackberry specific theme. i.e. it doesn't look like IBM are providing support for that theme with its mobile controls at this time. The Dojo controls themselves supports four theme, including blackberry so I suspect at this time you may need to tap into those themes manually.

Comment: Thanks, but any reason why there is a "blackberry" theme in the 8.5.3XL Discussion and Teamroom templates?  Somewhat misleading, no?